# Does !!window.chrome detect phone Chrome

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I test for Chrome like so:

```
!!window.chrome
```

Will this also be true for Chrome on a phone?

(yes, super easy to test IF you have a phone with Chrome!)

Comment: Did you not just already provide an answer to your own question? I'm confused??

Comment: Can't you try it yourself?

Comment: @ChristianMark: If it requires a phone with chrome, isn't it entirely plausible that OP can't indeed?

Comment: In fact, I haven't even got a smart phone.

Comment: **NO SMART PHONE!?** But how do you tell people about your breakfast?

Comment: @DavidHedlund: I know but they have this software in PC called the **[Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html)**. What I'm trying to say is that the question is general and you have to test every smartphone to justify your question. No offence meant.

Comment: @christianMark: Granted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tried it, and yes it does. (And I must type 30 characters)